# Can I do real time adb logcat keyword look up using python?

Tags: python, adb, jython

I am trying to run a test on android device and collect the logs using python and ADB. I want my python script to collect the ADB logcat logs and keep monitoring the logs, if any crash keywords(or any required keywords) are found during the run, take adb main radio bug-report and adb dump and save them in to particular folder in PC.

Can you please help with some ideas and documents.

Thank you.

Comment: Why does it have to be in Python? You could `adb logcat | tail -f | grep keyword` ... or something like that. (Assuming you are in a Unix system)

Comment: I don't think `tail -f` is necessary since `adb logcat` already "follows" the output by default.

Comment: I am using windows 10 PC. I am running some other test using python on devices and want to collect the logs and find the crash messages at the time of test.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Take a look at *subprocess* - http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html.

Once you have the *adb* output going into your Python script, you can do whatever you want to it - search live logs for keywords and then perform actions as required!